# A Python library for solving some integro-differential equations?

Tags: python, solver, finite-element-analysis

I have *a huge set of **coupled nonlinear integro-partial differential** equations*. After a long while trying to simplify the equations and solve them at least semi-analytically I have come to conclude there has been left no way for me but an efficient numerical method. Finite element seems most amenable as is based on Galerkin method which gives a **weak form** solution, so a great hope that it might finally solve the equations. But at the same time I am so new to this field to write the codes all from the scratch:

Is there any Python library already available that can efficiently do a Finite Element analysis?

Also I was interested if softwares like FEniCS/Dolphin might also solve integro-differential equations?

Comment: Try over on [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-element), e.g. [are-there-any-light-weight-fem-packages-around](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25222/are-there-any-light-weight-fem-packages-around)